# rJava Package installation failed (needed for xlsx package)

Tags: r, rjava, r-xlsx

When I want to install the xlsx package,  I get this error :

Loading required package: `rJava`

> Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
>     call: fun(libname, pkgname)
>     error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   package ‘rJava’ was built under R version 3.3.3 
>   Error: package ‘rJava’ could not be loaded

So I tried reinstalling `rJava`, but I get this :

> Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
>     call: fun(libname, pkgname)
>     error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   package ‘rJava’ was built under R version 3.3.3 
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’

Do you guys have any simple solution to this ? I am not very familiar with R, and I just need it to bootstrap some data.

Comment: not really an answer, but I overcame this by using `openxslx`(https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjs_-zotPXWAhVGtBQKHZWOAxsQFggzMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcran.r-project.org%2Fpackage%3Dopenxlsx&usg=AOvVaw0HGh8kKb3jtaGRY22pOpdT) instead. It offers the same  functionalities without having Java as a dependency.

Comment: Else, could you tell us whether you use r 32 or 64 bits? And the same for java? I think the problem could be related to using e.g., R 64 and Java 32.

Comment: You should accept the answer that was published! It works very well!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error recently (`R Error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry`). I found the solution [here](https://statisticsglobe.com/r-error-java-home-cannot-be-determined-from-the-registry). In brief, Joachim Schork identified the problem as not the xlsx package but rather the rjava package. He explained that the problem usually is, as hartmut said, running a 64 bit version of R and a 32 bit version of Java. To resolve the problem according to his recommendation, you need to download and install the 64 bit version of Java. In my case, the solution included *installing* Java on my machine as it was never installed previously.

Comment: Excellent answer! I had the same problem with the R package staplr. Your solution works for that problem.